# Change HTML page by using C# when it reloads

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my html page i've a default warning at the top of the page says to fill all input areas.

```
<span style="color:gray" class="help-block">Please enter value for all input fields.</span>
```

It is a page for adding some stuffs to database. When i click "add" button, it redirects `ActionResult` in my `C#` code. And inside this, according to entered input values, my code either inserts the stuff to database or reloads adding page which means unsuccessful to insert.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertStuff(Stuff stuff)
{
    if (stuffManager.InsertStuff(stuff))
        return RedirectToAction("ListStuffs", "StuffController");  //successfully inserted!!
    else
        return RedirectToAction("AddNewStuffForm", "StuffController"); //reload page, here is where i'd like to change warning in html
}
```

In else part, i'd like to load same `AddNewStuffForm` page but i want my warning to change color from gray to red as in:

```
<span style="color:red" class="help-block">Please enter value for all input fields.</span>
```

I do not know how to do that, as i deduced, i need to send something to `html` in `else` part of my `C#` code, but i do not know how to do that. I really did some research and some solutions offer to use some methods like `Page_Load`. However i am really beginner level at `html` and i have difficulties in offered solutions. Can anyone simply explain what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: RedirectToAction() tells your browser that it should go to another page. It's far from the best choice for doing something like this. How is this action invoked? Is this is an AJAX call? Then you should handle results in javascript. Do you render your views in MVC only? Then apply styles appropriately in the view returned. You need to specify more about your design

Comment: There are many ways to do that, you can store check values in ViewData for your else part and can recheck the ViewData values on rendering view and change your style accordingly, something like this<span style="color:@(ViewData["fail"])%;" class="help-block">Please enter value for all input fields.</span>

Comment: @Pranay i'm really thankful for your answer! It really helped. I've spent my half day to figure out, you saved my left half day.

Comment: @Pranay if you like, rewrite your comment as answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, you can store check values in ViewData for your else part and can recheck the ViewData values on rendering view and change your style accordingly, something like this

```
<span style="color:@(ViewData["fail"])%;" class="help-block">Please enter value for all input fields.</span>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're along the right lines.

- Normally, after a *successful* POST you would do a redirect to a new page.
- After an *unsuccessful* POST, you would remain on the same page, displaying an appropriate error. This is where you currently have it wrong.

So in your instance, rather than doing a redirect after the error, you could just return the current page instead. Without seeing the code you are using to generate your initial page I don't know exactly what that would look like in your case, but it's generally something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertStuff(Stuff stuff)
{
    if (stuffManager.InsertStuff(stuff))
        return RedirectToAction("ListStuffs", "StuffController"); //successfully inserted!!
    else
        return View("AddNewStuffForm", "StuffController", stuff); //reload page, here is where i'd like to change warning in html
}
```

The third parameter here is your original model - this can generally be used to re-populate the page with the values the user has input.

I would normally also validate the user input first - in ASP.Net MVC you might use something like a check of `ModelState.IsValid`

Answer (score -1):

Fill `ViewData` as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertStuff(Stuff stuff)
{
    if (stuffManager.InsertStuff(stuff)){
        return RedirectToAction("ListStuffs", "StuffController");//successfully inserted!!  
ViewData["PageMessage"] = "The message you want to print in case of success";    
}
        else{
            return RedirectToAction("AddNewStuffForm", "StuffController"); //reload page, here is where i'd like to change warning in html
ViewData["PageMessage"] = "The message you want to print in case of fail";
}
    }
```

Then print your message in `ViewData` in your view like this:

```
<p style="color:red;">@ViewData["PageMessage"]</p>
```

Comment: Using ViewData has been offered in comments of the question. In my case, keeping color in ViewData rather than warning text works. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I realized it was in comments after I wrote this answer. I am glad it helped.